# MS SQL Performance Monitoring over longer period

Tags: sql-server, monitoring

I am having an issue where the DB resources are being used up by someone in the business external to the application. Ignoring how unsafe and incompetent this is as it's not my business, how can I see the CPU usage of the DB server over a longer period of time. I use SysGauge to monitor the live statistics of the server but that only goes back over a 5 minute period. I've also tried the Microsoft SQL Server Performance Dashboard report but that only seems to go back over a 15 minute period. I need something that will allow me to look back over the current day's usage, does anyone know of either an inbuilt SQL report that can give me this or a open source external tool?

Microsoft SQL Server Performance Dashboard

[image]

SysGuage

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is quite a lot.

- [DBADash](https://github.com/trimble-oss/dba-dash) is opensource and great
- [Database Health Monitor](https://databasehealth.com/)
- [Solarwinds DPA](https://www.solarwinds.com/database-performance-analyzer)
- [RedGate SQL Monitor](https://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-monitor/)
- [Quest's Spotlight](https://www.quest.com/products/spotlight-on-sql-server-enterprise/)
- [Nagios Plugins](https://www.nagios.com/solutions/mssql-monitoring/)
- [Microsoft System Center Managment Packs](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56203)

to name but few.

Comment: That's brilliant, thank you so much